# Running drush on pressflow (D6) + nginx server

Tags: drush

SO, I have been using drush from past many years on an apache server and it has been working like charm. I have a multisite setup with Drupal and run around 100 subdomains. In my situation, I feel drush too easy to update certain things on the server for all subdomains.

Recently, we migrate our servers from apache to nginx(php-fpm) and also started using Pressflow instead of Drupal6. Since then I am unable to make any updates using drush on the subdomains. I run the drush command and it does not display any error, but also it does not do any updates on the subdomains. My server guy told me that drush is incompatible with php-fpm. IS that so?

Any ideas or solutions to make it working in a server running on nginx server and using Pressflow? If drush can't work, any links guiding how can I install a module on all subdomains using php would be great.

Comment: Can you run `php` from a shell at all?

Comment: yes, I can run it OK :)

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get php-fpm running on my local machine. I'm afraid you may need to ask drush guys for pointers. The fact it does not display any errors looks like a problem, even if malfunction is not drush fault.

Comment: Thanks @Mołot, I will ask Drush guys if I do not get an answer here. :(

Comment: Any luck on SO regarding this question?

Comment: Without some kind of error log it would be damn hard to help you.